# SOQL query to fetch records with special characters

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to fetch only records having special characters.

```
Select Id, Card_Number__c from Gift_Card__c where LastModifiedDate = TODAY
```

I want to fetch the records which have Special characters in `Card_Number__c`

Comment: Hi krishna, welcome to SFSE, where exactly are you stuck, what have you tried so far? please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour] and then [edit] your post. Thanks

Comment: It'll also help if you define what "special characters" you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that you can use is to define a formula field `Has_Special_Chars_In_Card_Number__c` and then query on that field being true

You can use the REGEX formula function to decide if there are special characters (non 0-9, A-Z, a-z)

Caveats - as this is a formula field, it will not be indexed so if your dataset is large, you might need to refine the query to look for only Gift Cards created in a specific, limited time range (like THIS_WEEK or LAST_N_DAYS:14)